# How can I set a minimal amount of numbers after the decimal dot (0.9=>0.90)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm using google bigquery, and a column has values I want to round. If I do, and the rounded value ends in a zero, the zero is not displayed.

I've tried the function FORMAT, which apparently has some .*number* function, but I have no idea how to use it. Whenever I include any 2 things separated by a comma inside its brackets, it complains that it only takes 1 value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help should include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it within the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: do you need this as a string for presentation purpose or still as a float for further calculation?

Answer (score 3):

You would use `FORMAT()` with the precision specifier.  For four decimal places always -- including zeros:

```
select format('%.4f', 1.23)
```

If the BQ [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#format) does not answer your questions, I find that that the function seems to be inspired by the classic C `printf()`/`sprintf()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Unaware if in BigQuery (haven't used it ever) there is a better way I guess this will fix your problem since I just tried it in their console.

Cast your float to a string and then check if your last digit is a 0. In case it's not add it:

```
SELECT case when RIGHT(cast(0.9 as string), 1) <> '0' then cast(0.9 as string)+'0' else cast(0.9 as string) end as FormattedNumber
```

Comment: This is the type of workaround I was considering, but this adds unnecessary 0s to already 2digit numbers that dont end in them.  
What it does right:
3.2=>3.20
What it doesn't do right:
3.23=>2.230